# eclipse and catkin_make not linking to ros.h dependencies

Tags: catkin, dependencies, publisher, linking, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

So I am working on a project where I basically want to create a node to take information from another, check it, then publish that information elsewhere. I was working on it yesterday and my coding environment was working fine(eclipse mars) however at one point yesterday it stopped recognizing all of my references to ros functions or message types. I thought it was just an eclipse specific thing so I tried to run it with catkin_make in my catkin workspace and that threw the same "undefined reference to ros*" errors as the build did in eclipse. Like I said, all was fine and dandy but now it isn't working. Below is the code for the node I am working with.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h"
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

/// ROS node name
const std::string ComponentName = "vel_cmd_filter_node";

const std::string J5CommandTopic = "/j5_cmd";
const std::string MoveBaseCmd = "/cmd_vel";

/// default forward linear velocity command in m/s
const float DefaultVelocityCmd = 0.0;

/// default angular velocity command in rad/s
const float DefaultTurnRateCmd = 0.0;

 /// the rate at which the component will publish commands
const int LoopRate = 10; // Hz

/// input value limits
/// these are just here for safety and do not reflect the actual limits of the platform
const double MaxVelocityCommand = 3.0;
const double MaxTurnRateCommand = 1.0;

geometry_msgs::Twist incoming;

void chatterCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist& velcmd);
geometry_msgs::Twist getCommandMsg();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

// get all command line arguments that aren't ROS specific
// these should be the velocity command parameters

// initialize ROS
std::vector<std::string> args;
geometry_msgs::Twist velcmd;


ros::init(argc,argv, ComponentName);
ros::removeROSArgs(argc, argv, args);
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe(MoveBaseCmd, 1000, chatterCallback);

// velocity command publisher
ros::Publisher velCmdPub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>(J5CommandTopic, 1000);


// asynchronous spinner to receive ROS messages
ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(0);

// loop rate used to control the frequency of message publication
ros::Rate loop_rate(LoopRate);

// set up message command
geometry_msgs::Twist cmdMsg = getCommandMsg();

// run loop
spinner.start();
while (ros::ok()) {

    // publish velocity command
    ROS_INFO("Sending Velocity Command: {%f, %f}", cmdMsg.linear.x,
            cmdMsg.angular.z);
    if (cmdMsg.linear.x || cmdMsg.angular.z) {
        velCmdPub.publish(cmdMsg);
    }
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
}

// shutdown component
spinner.stop();
ros::shutdown();

return 0;
}

void chatterCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist& velcmd) {
ROS_INFO("I heard this velocity: [%f]", velcmd.linear.x);
ROS_INFO("I heard this rotation: [%f]", velcmd.angular.z);
incoming = velcmd;
}

geometry_msgs::Twist getCommandMsg() {

geometry_msgs::Twist msg;

// body coordinates
// x is forward linear motion
msg.linear.x = DefaultVelocityCmd;

// rotation around the Z axis
msg.angular.z = DefaultTurnRateCmd;

// all other parameters are ignored in the Twist message
// NOTE:: args[0] is the name of the
if (incoming.linear.x) {
    try {
        msg.linear.x = incoming.linear.x;
        msg.linear.x = std::max(msg.linear.x, -MaxVelocityCommand);
        msg.linear.x = std::min(msg.linear.x, MaxVelocityCommand);
    }

    catch (...) {
        // could not parse the input, use default value
        msg.linear.x = DefaultVelocityCmd;
    }
}

if (incoming.angular.z) {
    try {
        msg.angular.z = incoming.angular.z;
        msg.angular.z = std::max(msg.angular.z, -MaxTurnRateCommand);
        msg.angular.z = std::min(msg.angular.z, MaxTurnRateCommand);
    }

    catch (...) {
        // could not parse the input, use default value
        msg.angular.z = DefaultTurnRateCmd;
    }
}
return msg;
}
```

Sorry about the wonky formatting...I'm still trying to get use to this posting stuff. Please let me know if you need more info! And thanks for the help!!!

Here is my cmake file like requested!

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(vel_cmd_filter)

 find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  j5_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  genmsg
)


 INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES vel_cmd_filter
  CATKIN_DEPENDS j5_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)


include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

 add_executable(vel_cmd_filter_node src/vel_cmd_filter_node.cpp)
```

I went through and deleted all the generated commented out things so you don't have to look at all that garbage. I also switched things around from my original post so I changed it to the most recent code.Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224749/eclipse-and-catkin_make-not-linking-to-ros.h-dependencies/) by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-21**:
Your CMakeLists.txt is the build file, which controls linking. Please **edit** your question to include your CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-21**:
Also, +1 for good formatting on your first post :)

**Comment by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on 2016-01-21**:
The cmake file wouldn't affect the build in eclipse though right? or am I crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not completely familiar with eclipse, but I presume that it uses the build rules defined in the CMakeLists.txt or that cmake generates the eclipse project, based on the CMakeLists.txt.

Either way, your CMakeLists.txt is missing the command which links your program against the ROS libraries. As described in the [C++ publisher tutorial, section 1.3](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)) and elsewhere, you need to add a `target_link_libraries()` to your CMakeLists.txt, like:

```
target_link_libraries(vel_cmd_filter_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I'm not sure why it was working before; perhaps that line was there and you accidentally deleted it from the end of the file?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on 2016-01-21**:
Sweet! Thanks! that worked for the catkin_make but Im still confused as to why eclipse still isn't recognizing the ros functions.

**Comment by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on 2016-01-21**:
I should probably specify that I have an eclipse project elsewhere(not in my catkin_ws directory) and I am using that to develop the source file and then just copying the src file to the source directory in my catkin_ws

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-21**:
I don't use Ecplise and don't know much about it, but this page describes how to use Ecplise and other IDEs with catkin: http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs . Probably much better than copying files back and forth.

**Comment by [Wagner2x](https://answers.ros.org/users/25690/wagner2x/) on 2016-02-01**:
Thanks for the help! Sorry I took so long to reply. It builds fine now however it is not publishing the information correctly. Should I start a new question or is that something you could answer here?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-01**:
I think that would be better as a new question.